# Mouse getting inactive , if no activity for 5 min , In Ubundu Lts 14.4 with gnome DE

Tags: gnome, mouse

Mouse is getting recursively  inactive , if no activity for 5 seconds. If i click the mouse buttons its came to active. I m using Ubundu LTS 14.4 , I suspect this issue after installation of gnome DE . Any idea about how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used Laptop tools , remove that , it will help you to resolve this issue